# Plotly in R creating a 3D animation

Tags: r, animation, 3d, plotly, r-plotly

I've been trying to produce an animated 3D scatter plot in Plotly to show how sensor data is changing with time. Ploty appears to bin the time frame correctly and puts all the sensors information in a timeframe, however rather than updating the trace at each time frame it just adds another to all time frames. Any ideas one how to get plotly to replot at each timeframe? My code is

```
fig1 <- short_all_data %>%
  plot_ly(x=~one, 
          y=~two, 
          z=~three,
          size = ~temperature,
          color = ~temperature,
          frame = ~time,
          mode ='markers',
          type = 'scatter3d')
  fig1
```

The data frame is

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 
32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 
32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 32761, 
32761, 32761, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 
32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 
32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775, 32775), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), sensor_number = c("sensor_1", "sensor_2", 
"sensor_3", "sensor_4", "sensor_5", "sensor_6", "sensor_7", "sensor_8", 
"sensor_9", "sensor_10", "sensor_11", "sensor_12", "sensor_13", 
"sensor_14", "sensor_15", "sensor_16", "sensor_17", "sensor_18", 
"sensor_19", "sensor_20", "sensor_21", "sensor_22", "sensor_23", 
"sensor_24", "sensor_1", "sensor_2", "sensor_3", "sensor_4", 
"sensor_5", "sensor_6", "sensor_7", "sensor_8", "sensor_9", "sensor_10", 
"sensor_11", "sensor_12", "sensor_13", "sensor_14", "sensor_15", 
"sensor_16", "sensor_17", "sensor_18", "sensor_19", "sensor_20", 
"sensor_21", "sensor_22", "sensor_23", "sensor_24"), temperature = c(12137, 
12298, 10743, 10644, 9787, 10617, 9466, 9150, 10051, 8706, 10094, 
9541, 10326, 9983, 9494, 10044, 10126, 10436, 11848, 12141, 12216, 
11348, 0, 0, 12422, 11876, 10556, 10763, 10284, 10365, 8760, 
9684, 10068, 9649, 9940, 9913, 10316, 9527, 9939, 10378, 9920, 
9986, 11946, 12461, 11804, 11230, 50000, 0), one = c(1, 5, 1, 
5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 
1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 
5, 1, 5), two = c(1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 
5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 
1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5), three = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
5)), row.names = c(NA, -48L), groups = structure(list(sensor_number = c("sensor_1", 
"sensor_10", "sensor_11", "sensor_12", "sensor_13", "sensor_14", 
"sensor_15", "sensor_16", "sensor_17", "sensor_18", "sensor_19", 
"sensor_2", "sensor_20", "sensor_21", "sensor_22", "sensor_23", 
"sensor_24", "sensor_3", "sensor_4", "sensor_5", "sensor_6", 
"sensor_7", "sensor_8", "sensor_9"), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 
25L), c(10L, 34L), c(11L, 35L), c(12L, 36L), c(13L, 37L), c(14L, 
38L), c(15L, 39L), c(16L, 40L), c(17L, 41L), c(18L, 42L), c(19L, 
43L), c(2L, 26L), c(20L, 44L), c(21L, 45L), c(22L, 46L), c(23L, 
47L), c(24L, 48L), c(3L, 27L), c(4L, 28L), c(5L, 29L), c(6L, 
30L), c(7L, 31L), c(8L, 32L), c(9L, 33L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[produced plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CtO1.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide us with the output of `dput(short_all_data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended your example data a little. Your code gives me the output I'd expect:

```
library(plotly)

short_all_data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              time = c("09:06:01","09:06:01",
                       "09:06:01","09:06:01","09:06:01","09:06:01","09:06:01",
                       "09:06:01","09:06:01","09:06:01","09:06:02","09:06:02",
                       "09:06:02","09:06:02","09:06:02","09:06:02","09:06:02",
                       "09:06:02","09:06:02","09:06:02","09:06:03",
                       "09:06:03","09:06:03","09:06:03","09:06:03","09:06:03",
                       "09:06:03","09:06:03","09:06:03","09:06:03","09:06:04",
                       "09:06:04","09:06:04","09:06:04","09:06:04","09:06:04",
                       "09:06:04","09:06:04","09:06:04","09:06:04",
                       "09:06:05","09:06:05","09:06:05","09:06:05","09:06:05",
                       "09:06:05","09:06:05","09:06:05","09:06:05","09:06:05",
                       "09:06:06","09:06:06","09:06:06","09:06:06","09:06:06",
                       "09:06:06","09:06:06","09:06:06","09:06:06",
                       "09:06:06"),
     sensor_number = c("sensor_1","sensor_2",
                       "sensor_3","sensor_4","sensor_5","sensor_6","sensor_7",
                       "sensor_8","sensor_9","sensor_10","sensor_1","sensor_2",
                       "sensor_3","sensor_4","sensor_5","sensor_6",
                       "sensor_7","sensor_8","sensor_9","sensor_10","sensor_1",
                       "sensor_2","sensor_3","sensor_4","sensor_5","sensor_6",
                       "sensor_7","sensor_8","sensor_9","sensor_10","sensor_1",
                       "sensor_2","sensor_3","sensor_4","sensor_5",
                       "sensor_6","sensor_7","sensor_8","sensor_9","sensor_10",
                       "sensor_1","sensor_2","sensor_3","sensor_4","sensor_5",
                       "sensor_6","sensor_7","sensor_8","sensor_9",
                       "sensor_10","sensor_1","sensor_2","sensor_3","sensor_4",
                       "sensor_5","sensor_6","sensor_7","sensor_8","sensor_9",
                       "sensor_10"),
       temperature = c(12137L,12298L,10743L,10644L,
                       9787L,10617L,9466L,9150L,10051L,8706L,9651L,8001L,
                       7000L,9000L,12000L,15000L,14032L,12345L,12340L,
                       12342L,12300L,11000L,11100L,11200L,11300L,11400L,
                       11500L,11600L,11700L,11800L,12137L,12298L,10743L,
                       10644L,9787L,10617L,9466L,9150L,10051L,8706L,9651L,
                       8001L,7000L,9000L,12000L,15000L,14032L,12345L,
                       12340L,12342L,12300L,11000L,11100L,11200L,11300L,11400L,
                       11500L,11600L,11700L,11800L),
               one = c(1L,5L,1L,5L,1L,5L,1L,5L,
                       1L,5L,2L,5L,1L,5L,2L,5L,1L,5L,2L,5L,1L,5L,
                       2L,5L,1L,5L,2L,5L,1L,5L,1L,5L,1L,5L,1L,5L,
                       1L,5L,1L,5L,2L,5L,1L,5L,2L,5L,1L,5L,2L,5L,1L,
                       5L,2L,5L,1L,5L,2L,5L,1L,5L),
               two = c(1L,1L,5L,5L,1L,1L,5L,5L,
                       1L,1L,1L,2L,5L,2L,1L,2L,5L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,
                       5L,2L,1L,2L,5L,2L,1L,2L,1L,1L,5L,5L,1L,1L,
                       5L,5L,1L,1L,1L,2L,5L,2L,1L,2L,5L,2L,1L,2L,1L,
                       2L,5L,2L,1L,2L,5L,2L,1L,2L),
             three = c(0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                       2L,2L,0L,0L,2L,0L,1L,1L,2L,1L,2L,2L,2L,0L,
                       0L,0L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,1L,
                       1L,1L,2L,2L,0L,0L,2L,0L,1L,1L,2L,1L,2L,2L,2L,
                       0L,0L,0L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L)
)

fig1 <- short_all_data %>%
  plot_ly(x=~one, 
          y=~two, 
          z=~three,
          size = ~temperature,
          color = ~temperature,
          frame = ~time,
          mode ='markers',
          type = 'scatter3d')
fig1
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks ismirsehregal, I can see what you did to get it working and it looks good. I was wondering if you could explain the reasoning why the data frame you created works and the original one I have does not. Looking at the df you created the only difference I can see is "string_as_factors" which keeps time data as time rather than a number and the addition of "L" after the variables, which seems to imply you are telling R this value is an integer . The sample data I posted is only part of a much larger set (69000 obversation) so it would be handy to understand.

Comment: I extended your example data to have different values for the column `time` which you pass to `frame`. Each frame represents the data displayed according to one of the slider ticks. Without knowing your data it's hard to tell whats going wrong. You can post a subset here via copying the result of `dput(head(short_all_data, 50))` to your question.

Comment: Thanks ismisehregal using your dataframe I was able to figure out what the difference was and correct it. To put it simply the string type and maybe some grouping was wrong in my df so after some conversion it produced the correct plot